# How do I make <leader>keys do nothing if they aren't mapped?

Tags: key-bindings, leader

Right now by default, when I do `<leader>keys`, if `keys` is not mapped to anything it will run those keys as if I did not map them (*i.e*, doing `<leader>o` would just do `o` if I don't map it to anything). Is there a way to make it so it doesn't do anything if the leader key combination isn't mapped to anything?